# Print formatting with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, printing

I am trying to format the print function so that I can create spacing between the string array `a[0]` and `c`. The `type` for `a[0]` is `<class 'numpy.str_'>`. The `a` array below has a class for `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` but I couldn't turn a into `<class 'numpy.str_'>` for this example. When I have `<class 'numpy.str_'>` as the type I cannot do spacing with the print functions. How would I be able to create spacing and have the spacing in the print function when `a` is of type `<class 'numpy.str_'>`

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array(["asddfsdf","adsdasdasd"])
b= 24
c= 40
print(f'{b:<10} {a[0]:<15} {c}')
```

Output:

```
24         asddfsdf 40
```

Expected Output:

```
24         asddfsdf        40
```

Comment: i get your expected output :)

Comment: I get my expected output too but `a` has to be of type `<class 'numpy.str_'>`  instead of `<class 'numpy.str_'>`

Comment: `a` is `numpy.ndarray`.  `a[0]`, an element of the array  is `numpy.str_`
`

Comment: I don't see the difference: `<class 'numpy.str_'>` instead of `<class 'numpy.str_'>`